# Can you teleport a player if they click on an item in their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In some Minecraft multiplayer servers, you can simply click on on a item in your inventory, and you will be teleported to somewhere or to someone.

Is there a way to create this same scenario on a vanilla sever with commands?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "click"? Holding it in your player's hand and left-clicking or right-clicking, or opening the inventory and picking it up with the mouse?

Comment: @Skylinerw any three of those methods would be great for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the item is meant to be locked in a particular slot in their inventory, you can detect when that item is no longer in that slot, indicating that the player has chosen that item for whatever it represents.

#### 1.8

**Prerequisites:**

Objective to track when the player has selected the item.

```
/scoreboard objectives add MadeChoice dummy
```

**Clock commands:**

The following must run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Mark players as having selected the item first.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a MadeChoice 1
   ```
2. If the item is still in its location, set their score back to 0. The example here is a stone block in slot 10.

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a MadeChoice 0 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b,Slot:10b}]}
   ```
3. Target players that have a "MadeChoice" score of 1, which would be those that had moved stone away from the necessary slot.

   ```
   /tp @a[score_MadeChoice_min=1] 0 64 0
   ```

#### 1.9

**Clock commands:**

The following must run in numerical order on a clock.

1. Mark players as having selected the item first.

   ```
   /scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!MadeChoice] add MadeChoice
   ```
2. If the item is still in its location, set their score back to 0. The example here is a stone block in slot 10.

   ```
   /scoreboard players tag @a[tag=MadeChoice] remove MadeChoice {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b,Slot:10b}]}
   ```
3. Target players that have a "MadeChoice" score of 1, which would be those that had moved stone away from the necessary slot.

   ```
   /tp @a[tag=MadeChoice] 0 64 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the mod essentials. After you have installed it, grab the item you want then type the following:
**/tphere (username.)**

Replace (username) with the user's in game name.
or **/tp (username) @p**
You can replace @p with your or the target's username. Or you can put coordinates there if you want to to go to a specific spot.

But you can't in vanilla, unless you use command blocks and use **/tp @p (Coordinates.)**

Comment: "Is there a way to create this same scenario on a **vanilla sever**", and it is possible with command blocks.